# How to tear down selenium webdriver when the @tests are in different classes

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver, teardown

I have about 5 different classes with JUnit tests (selenium tests).
I need a way to teardown the webdriver at the end of the program.
So I need to know where to put the @AfterClass and how to pass the driver to it so it can be closed.

I thought of creating a test suit and implement the &AfterClass tearDownClass() there. But I'm not sure how to pass the driver to it to close.

Comment: it has nothing to do with Selenium, this is basic OOP concept. please read few books on core java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
[OneTimeTearDown]
        public void SetupTestTeardown()
        {
            KillDriver();
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }
```

The OneTimeTearDown attribute is inherited from any base class. Therefore, if a base class has defined a OneTimeTearDown method, that method will be called after any test methods in the derived class.

You may define a OneTimeTearDown method in the base class and another in the derived class. NUnit will call base class OneTimeTearDown methods after those in the derived classes.

Comment: thanks, I have a super class which is inherited by all of my test classes. However it does not have driver attribute. The driver is instantiated in a different class. So again - how do I pass the driver to this inherited class so I can kindly kill it?

Answer (score 0):

Add @BeforeClass to your superclass. Initiate the driver in that. Due to this, the test classes will also inherit the driver.

Add the driver teardown in your superclass in @AfterClass